# Getting error in a batch file while running python script converted to exe

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script, `count_test.py`, that runs well in my remote desktop. It takes 3 records from one table and inserts them into another table.

I have created this python script using my python local environment within `C:\Process\test` folder, then converted to an exe file, complete with the db connections ini file, using the `auto-py-to-exe` python library.

After running the library, a folder was created with name `count_test` under the folder `C:\Process\test`. This folder was then moved to another server to run exe in a batch file.

When I click on the exe, the script is running okay, but when I call it in the batch file, it is giving an error.

My idea is to hand over the batch file to support team to run on demand. Can someone take a look and give me the solution?

batch script:

```bash
@echo off
"C:\Process\count_test\count_test.exe"
pause
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "count_test.py", line 27, in <module>
File "configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'oracle'
[5796] Failed to execute script 'count_test' due to unhandled exception!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I need a solution for the above problem.

Comment: Often such problems occur when the current directory when the executable is invoked is different for the two methods.

Comment: That's an error generated by the compiled Python program. Not the batch file. IOTW, you'll still get the error is that program is run directly from the command prompt, instead of from within a batch file. So, this is a Python problem. Not batch file problem.